# Moving Application from Desktop to Web, Set of Skills required?

Tags: java

A Java Desktop Application, with a very basic UI, that could properly just be a Simple Generated non interactive HTML Webpage. In my mind this would means rewriting the presentation layer only, while the core is still run from server and should required no modification.

Would it be easier for someone already familiar with the codebase, but has little web application experience to take on the job or someone who is experience with web development but never touched the project before.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how well the apps are written . Architecturally you want proper seperation of concerns, none of the fuzzy monolithic quick bodge stuff most business's mandate in complete ignorance.

Validation is often a headache.

Presentation across lots of different browsers.

Licensing, and possibly payment model.

And above all security, there's all sorts of stuff we do on a`windows client because we rely on it being secure, that are`walking talking exploits as`soon as you expose them to the underweb world. Last thing you want is for your first foray into on-line to get taken out by a`nasty.